# ¿Cómo eliminar duplicados con condición de fecha? en R

Tags: r, condiciones, eliminar-duplicados

Tengo una base de datos con ID y fecha de inicio de síntomas. En algunos casos están mal cargadas las fechas, por lo que tienen algunos días de diferencia, pero es el mismo caso. Por lo tanto, quiero eliminar los duplicados de aquellas fechas que entre ellas tengan menos de tres meses de diferencia.

Necesito eliminar los casos duplicados en los que la diferencia de fechas sean menores a 3 meses entre sí (es decir, dejar uno y eliminar uno). Si tengo dos duplicados en los que la diferencia entre fechas es mayor a 3 meses quiero dejar ambos registros.

Dejo un ejemplo, en este caso, del ID 36269387 me debería quedar con un solo registro (porque asumo que es el mismo caso que se cargó mal una fecha) y del ID 17137360 me debería quedar con los dos registros (porque son dos casos distintos, en años distintos)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

El código que escribí fue el siguiente:

```
for (i in 1: nrow(coqueluche)) {
if (i == 1) {
sin_dups <- coqueluche[i, ,drop=FALSE]
} else {
ultimo <- tail(sin_dups,1)
diferencia <- interval(ultimo$FECHA_MIN, coqueluche$FECHA_MIN[i]) %/% months(1)
if (diferencia >= 1 | ultimo$NRO_DOC != coqueluche$NRO_DOC[i]) {
sin_dups <- rbind(sin_dups, coqueluche[i, ,drop=FALSE])
}
  }
}
```

Le puse "1" en lugar de "3" porque necesito que me elimine los que tengan una fecha menor a un mes en vez de menor a tres meses.
De la base sin dups seleccioné los duplicados por DNI y se puede ver cómo por ejemplo el caso 44444444 me tendría que haber eliminado una fila porque la diferencia de fechas es menor a un mes, al igual que el caso 66666666.

Puede que tenga que ver con el formato de la fecha? No logro que me lo muestre como dd-mm-aaaa, me lo muestra como aaaa-mm-dd.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenida Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Julieta, no es algo sencillo de resolver, la definición que diste no alcanza,  ¿qué pasa si tienes tres observaciones A, B, C, cada una con dos meses de distancia entre ellas?  ¿con cual nos quedamos?  según tu definición  A y B serían duplicados, y B y C también, sin embargo A y C no lo serían. ¿Has intentado resolverlo de alguna forma? Si es así agrega a tu pregunta el código de lo que intentaste.

Comment: Únicamente tengo ID repetidos una vez, es decir, dos registros con el mismo ID, en ningún caso tengo 3 o más. No sé por dónde empezar el código, por eso no hice ningún intento aún.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema no es simple, te voy a plantear un ejemplo:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(3629387, 3629387, 3629387, 17137360),
  Fecha = as.Date(c("15/01/2023", "28/02/2023", "15/05/2023",
                    "12/05/2023"), "%d/%m/%Y")
)

df %>%
  arrange(ID, Fecha) %>% 
  mutate(DifMeses = interval(lag(Fecha), Fecha) %/% months(1)) %>% 
  filter(ID == 3629387)

       ID      Fecha DifMeses
1 3629387 2023-01-15       NA
2 3629387 2023-02-28        1
3 3629387 2023-05-15        2
```

En el `ID = 3629387` planteo la gran dificultad que veo tiene tu pregunta. Claramente la segunda fila es una repetición de la primera, hay una distancia de un mes, el problema es la tercer fila, con respecto a la segunda hay dos meses por lo que podría considerarse una repetición, sin embargo, entiendo que ese no es el criterio adecuado. Deberíamos considerar la segunda fila como repetición, eliminarla y mirar la tercer fila con respecto a la anterior, que (al haber eliminado la segunda) sería la primera, y ahora sí podemos considerar la tercer fila como válida.

Esto no puede resolverse de forma "vectorial", lamentablemente hay que iterar secuencialmente por cada observación. Fundamental para la solución que planteo es que (a) Las fechas sean fechas (b) los datos estén ordenados por ID y Fecha.

```
library(lubridate)

for (i in 1: nrow(df)) {
  if (i == 1) {
    sin_dups <- df[i, ,drop=FALSE]
  } else {
    ultimo <- tail(sin_dups,1)
    diferencia <- interval(ultimo$Fecha, df$Fecha[i]) %/% months(1)
    if (diferencia >= 3 || ultimo$ID != df$ID[i]) {
      sin_dups <- rbind(sin_dups, df[i, ,drop=FALSE])
    }
  }
}

sin_dups


        ID      Fecha
1  3629387 2023-01-15
3  3629387 2023-05-15
4 17137360 2023-05-12
```

Importante: este código, elimina cualquier duplicado de menos de dos meses es decir si tienes A, B, C y B y C tienen una distancia de no más de 2 meses con respecto a A, quedará solo A. Si quieres eliminar una sola fila cada vez hay que llevar la cuenta de los borrados para solo eliminar uno.

```
for (i in 1: nrow(df)) {
  if (i == 1) {
    sin_dups <- df[i, ,drop=FALSE]
    sin_dups$Borrados <- 0
  } else {
    ultimo <- tail(sin_dups,1)
    diferencia <- interval(ultimo$Fecha, df$Fecha[i]) %/% months(1)
    if (diferencia >= 3 || ultimo$ID != df$ID[i] || ultimo$Borrados == 1) {
      sin_dups <- rbind(sin_dups, cbind(df[i, ,drop=FALSE],Borrados=0))
    } else {
      sin_dups$Borrados[nrow(sin_dups)] <- sin_dups$Borrados[nrow(sin_dups)] + 1 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Una vez que corro el primer chunk me elimina algunos duplicados. Para hacer el proceso iterativo tengo que volver a correr el mismo? Muchas gracias

Comment: No debería bastar con correrlo una sola vez.

Comment: Entonces qué tendría que hacer después de correrlo una vez?

Comment: Nada, el data.frame `sin_dups` es el resultado final  dónde debieran haberse quitado los duplicados según la definición y supuestos que indico en mi respuesta. ¿Cuál es la dificultad que has tenido?

Comment: Me elimina algunos registros pero no todo. Cuando miro el data frame sin_dups hay algunos que por ejemplo tienen fechas con 4 días de diferencia, es decir que no se eliminaron bien

Comment: Del mismo Id? Los datos están ordenados tal como lo mencione en mi respuesta? sin esto último no te va a funcionar. Por otro lado, podes armar un ejemplo reproducible con los casos que mencionas?

Comment: Te muestro lo que probé hasta ahora:

coqueluche$FECHA_MIN <- as.Date(coqueluche$FECHA_MIN,format ="%d/%m/%Y")
coqueluche <- coqueluche[with(coqueluche, order(IDEVENTOCASO, FECHA_MIN)), ]

for (i in 1: nrow(coqueluche)) {
  if (i == 1) {
    sin_dups <- coqueluche[i, ,drop=FALSE]
  } else {
    ultimo <- tail(sin_dups,1)
    diferencia <- interval(ultimo$FECHA_MIN, coqueluche$FECHA_MIN[i]) %/% months(1)
    if (diferencia >= 1 || ultimo$IDEVENTOCASO != coqueluche$IDEVENTOCASO[i]) {
      sin_dups <- rbind(sin_dups, coqueluche[i, ,drop=FALSE])
    }
  }
}

Comment: Pero por que haces `diferencia >= 1 `? en mi ejemplo `diferencia >= 3`. Pero más allá de eso, sin ver los datos es imposible darte alguna respuesta a tú comentario.

Comment: Ahí creo que logré que funcione la fórmula. Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

En base al último comentario, una manera de lograr esto es usando `dplyr`. Lo único a considerar, es que no se especifica cual de los dos registros deseas mantener y cual descartar. En este caso, el filtro descarta el primer registro del ID duplicado.

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(3629387, 3629387, 17137360, 17137360),
  Fecha = c("15/10/2023", "18/10/2023", "25/03/2021", "10/05/2020")
)

df %>%
  mutate(Fecha = as.Date(Fecha, format = "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(month_difference = (max(Fecha) - min(Fecha)) / 30,
         month_difference = paste0(round(month_difference, 0), " months")) %>%
  filter((as.numeric(gsub(" months", "", month_difference)) > 3 | duplicated(ID)))

        ID Fecha      month_difference
     <dbl> <date>     <chr>           
1  3629387 2023-10-18 0 months        
2 17137360 2021-03-25 11 months       
3 17137360 2020-05-10 11 months
```

Comment: Gracias, intenté esa fórmula pero no logro que funcione. Creo que es porque tengo más de un caso duplicado por ID, es decir, por ejemplo tres ID iguales con cada uno una fecha distinta.  En este caso ¿cómo podría solucionarlo?